# How to Configure Magento2 with Gulp instead Grunt

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, grunt

How to configure Magento2 with Gulp instead Grunt. 
Anyone have idea ?

Comment: Was my response the one you where looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I personally use this simple gulpfile.js to process my css to the pub folders.

```
// Load gulp and plug-ins
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    jshint      = require('gulp-jshint'),
    less        = require('gulp-less'),
    concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename      = require('gulp-rename'),
    gutil       = require('gulp-util'),
    livereload  = require('gulp-livereload'),
    sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


// Generate less to CSS.
gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/theme.less'])
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write() )
        .pipe( livereload() )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/nl_NL/css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/de_DE/css'))
});


// Watch Files For Changes and livereload
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/**/*.less', ['less']);
});


gulp.task('default', ['less']);
```

Comment: What about for languages though?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I meant what about for JS files? This is really good BTW

Comment: How to get output using this code?

Comment: Do you know how to create critical.css using gulp or grunt?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to try [SnowdogApps/magento2-frontools](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-frontools)

With this you have gulp and also sass support

Comment: This is no longer the case, Frontools only supports Sass now

Comment: @BenCrook just use version 0.11.4 and lower

Comment: That means missing out on new features and bug fixes, not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

there is an ongoing discussion in including gulp to magento2 here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2104

alen kent also wrote a blog post on how to integrate it in the current release:
http://alankent.me/2016/01/27/gulp-et-al-in-magento-2/

I think the process will be still much enhanced for fe developers since many parts of the frontend workflow are pretty hard to change currently. I hope  and think magento2 will be more flexibel with this in the future like it is in most cases for the backend development.

Comment: That links are very informative. Thanks for sharing boss !

Answer (score 1):

some step :

- apt-get install nodejs and tape ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
- go to root prject and : apt-get install npm
- npm install --global gulp-cli and tape npm install --save-dev gulp
- donwload gulp.js from https://github.com/poddubny/magento2-gulp   =>     npm install gulp-less npm install gulp-sourcemaps  npm install gulp-cssmin  npm install gulp-livereload  npm install gulp-if
  npm install -g graceful-fs
- bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --locale="en_US" --area="frontend" --theme="Ibnab/Salam"
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

the complete video tutorials is here : http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-video-introduction-for-using-gulp-in-frontend

Comment: Hi inab do you have the script the repo is not there anymore

Comment: try from here https://ufile.io/xhw1b

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that stays with core magento style and structures, our team has developed this [magento-2-gulp](https://github.com/bobmotor/magento-2-gulp) that supports:

- default magento 2 project structure with theme config inside `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js`
- installation with `composer`
- `.less`
- `browsersync` and `liverreload`
- compiling es6+ with `Babel`
- creating `svg` sprites

Answer (score 0):

I use this to compile LESS locally.

```
// Load gulp and plug-ins
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    less        = require('gulp-less'),
    concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
    rename      = require('gulp-rename'),
    gutil       = require('gulp-util'),
    sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

function styles_l() {
  return gulp.src('frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/styles-l.less')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css'));
}

function styles_m() {
  return gulp.src('frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/styles-m.less')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css'));
}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch('frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/**/*.less', styles_l);
}

var build = gulp.series(gulp.parallel(styles_l,styles_m));

exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = build;
```